# onChange not triggering when the draft editor is in readOnly mode

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, draftjs

onChange event not triggering when the draft editor is in the readOnly mode. I wanna keep the readOnly mode, but it has to trigger the onChange event, so that I can save my work.

```
             <Editor
                readOnly={true}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                ref={(e) => { this.editor = e; }}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoComplete="off"
                autoCorrect="off"
                spellCheck={false}
              />
```

Comment: you can just use `onChange` when `readOnly` is off,  "`all editability disabled`" => [ref](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor.html#readonly)

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing this for draft js accessibility. I know that the editability is disabled when readOnly is on. I have a way around to make it editable. Now I need a solution to save the work.

Answer (score 0):

as the following tells, you can trigger your save actions on the editor change or blur event (but for performance I recommend blur):

```js
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState();
const [editable, setEditable]=useState(false);
const editorRef = useRef(null);

const onChange = (editorState) => {
  setEditorState(editorState);
};

const onBlur = (state) => {
   //  convertToRaw from draft-js;
  const contentState = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());
  // save contentState      
};

return (
  <Editor
    editorState={editorState}
    readOnly={!editable}
    onChange={onChange}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    ref={editorRef}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoComplete="off"
    autoCorrect="off"
    spellCheck={false}
  />
)
```